# Find Replace in .txt files in a directory

Tags: windows

I have a lot of script files (all files have SQL or Trans SQL) say around 2000 files that we used to add with the passage of the time. Now the problem is that in most of the scripts the owner of the database object is not defined and due to my current requirement I must have to set the owner of the database object. How can I update all the script files easily.
One approach is to open each file look for create word and replace/append the owner name before the create key word. I want to do it for all the script files in the directory.
Any ideas?

I want something like find replace.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Who can tell. There are zillions of search and replace scripts in all languages and for all operating systems around. Most of the text-editors I know have a "replace in files" feature (like notepad++). Even my file manager can do this. It would be more substantial to know if the part you want to replace is the same in all 2000 Files. Or are there differences in spacing, quotes, syntax or else? Do you need straight text replacement or a fancy grep? In later case show us some examples.

Comment: Well it is not very straight forward.
say one file has this "create table ABC ...."
another file may have "CREATE TABLE "DBA"."DEF"
Now i only want to update those files which have the text like first file.

Comment: I want to add the "DBA". before the object name in all files where it is not set.

Comment: Your question is too vague. You write "may have", which does not specify the problem clearly. You should (1) figure out exactly what you want to do - spell out the details clearly, like 'Exactly how do I recognize a line that needs to be updated?" and "Exactly what update needs to be performed?", and then (2) start writing a script that implements your specification, and then (3) if you get stuck, post a question.